# double recursive education example

Tags: python, recursion

This function is just not making sense to me.  Ive added print statements all over the place to figure out whats going on and I still dont get it.  I'd be grateful if someone could explain this to me.

```
def f(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    return f(f(s[1:])) + s[0]

print(f("mat"))
```

This is what I see happening.  So we start with string of length 3 and bypass the if statement.  We work on the inside f(s[1:]) first.  So now we have a string of length 2 ("at") that again bypasses the if statement and enters the f(s[1]) which gives us string of length 1 ("t") that enters the if statement finally and returns "t".  This is where the trail goes cold for me.

From my print statements, I see a new string of length 2 is created and subsequent "a" gets returned.  The final product ends up being "atm".  I get the "m" being tagged on the end thanks to the "+ s[0]" part but why is it "atm" and not "tam"?

I've honestly spent a few hours on this and cant make it rain.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a pen and paper? Its not extremely complex so I'd recommend that you draw your call stack with the current state of the variable. It would be better for you to find it out yourself than have someone explain it to you.

Comment: @stazima - Since he's spent a few hours on it already, I think the OP will be better off with it explained more explicitly, otherwise he'll just end up banging his head against the same wall he's been hitting so far.

Answer (score 5):

Expand the whole thing out into long steps by filling in the function calls with what they are doing. Deal with the brackets from the deepest/most embedded first. Deal with function calls before addition.

I'm going to ignore the string quotes everywhere for clarity.

```
f(mat)           -> mat is 3 chars:
                    call f on at for f(at), and call f on that.
                    add m.

f(f(at))+m       -> inner f(at), at is 2 chars:
                    call f on t for f(t), and call f on that.
                    add a.

f(f(f(t))+a)+m   -> innermost f(t) returns t.

f(f(t)+a)+m      -> inner f(t) returns t as well.

f(ta)+m          -> [here, the first f(f(at)) has been reduced to f(ta)]
                    ta is 2 chars:
                    call f on a for f(a), and call f on that.
                    add t.

f(f(a))+t+m      -> inner f(a) returns a.

f(a)+t+m         -> f(a) returns a as well.

a + t + m        -> 

atm              -> everything reduces to atm.
```

Comment: Why call f twice on at? Doesn't it call f on at, then f on the value returned by the first call?

Comment: @stenci It does, and that's what I mean by "call f twice". Perhaps that's not a good way to describe it... I've reworded it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Short version: the `a` and `t` are getting swapped *twice*, so the inner `f("at")` call returns `"ta"`, then the outer `f()` call gets passed `"ta"` and returns `"at"`.

Longer version: I won't spell it out explicitly for you since you won't learn as much that way, but consider this function, which is *totally equivalent*:

```
def f2(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    x = f2(s[1:])
    return f2(x) + s[0]

print(f2("mat"))
```

When you call `f2("mat")`, `s[1:]` is `"at"`. Now, what does `f2("at")` return? Plug that value (the value of `x`) into the `f2(x) + s[0]` expression and see what you get.

Try running through the values of `f2("at")` and `f2("ta")` and see if you can spot what's happening. If you still need help after another 15-20 minutes of work, comment on this answer and I'll expand on it some more.

Comment: I can see where you are going but its still not happening for me.  My hangup is related to fact that s[0] = "a" and then it equals "t".  So the first loop  returns "t" + s[0] ("a") = "ta".  Then it goes through again and reverses those two.  But I dont get why it goes through a second time and then why s[0] becomes "m" again.

Comment: `s[0]` isn't one thing, it exists inside the function, but it exists once *for every time `f()` is called* and it only exists *inside a given call*. Since `f()` gets called lots of times, there are lots of versions of `s[0]` being created throughout the whole program run. It doesn't "become m again", it's a different s[0] in a different f() call.

Comment: @futevolei The fact that you referred to what's happening as a "loop" indicates a fundamental problem in how you're thinking about this.  There is no loop.  There are only function calls.  If you know how to trace through what happens in a function call, then the fact that the function makes another function call (to itself) shouldn't interfere with your ability to trace what's happening overall.  If you think it's a loop, all bets are off.

Comment: @futevolei - I won't be able to write a full answer for a couple hours, but maybe @TessellatingHeckler's comment will help you. Remember that *all* these variables only have values inside the body of `f()` and aren't carried out to the outside of the function call. So get a piece of paper and draw yourself a **new** box for every function call. Inside the box, write the values that `s` (along with `s[1:]` and `s[0]`) have for **this** function call. And you might want to use the `f2()` function that I presented when doing this, because you'll be slightly less confused that way.

Comment: no problem, let me try and clarify what I was getting at.  Starting from the beginning with "mat".  It bypasses the if statement.  Then it gets put into the function.  I assumed the computer didnt get past the inner function and therefore doesnt add s[0] but instead it actually executes the whole line and takes off the "m".

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a surprisingly interesting function, and I can see why it's confusing you. I assume that you're trying to understand the function as a whole, and that's actually not going to work well here.

Right now, there are two parts to this function - handling the case where it's empty or there is only one letter in the string, and handling the case where there are at least two letters in the string. However, this is deceptive because it effectively applies a different operation depending on how many letters there are in the string!

So let's think of the function in a non-recursive way: if the string is too short, just return the string. Otherwise, apply *some function* twice to all but the first character of the string, and then add the first character to the end of the result. Don't think of it as being the same function, just think of it as being some unknown function.

In code:

```
def f(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    return other_f(other_f(s[1:])) + s[0]
```

**Down the rabbit hole:**

So how do we define this `other_f`? Let's see what behavior it needs to have for certain string lengths. If `len(s)` is 2, then we know `s[1:]` is one character, so `other_f` will just return `s[1:]`. In code:

```
def f2(s): # For when len(s)==2
    #if statement is not used
    #return other_f(other_f(s[1:])) + s[0] becomes
    #return other_f(other_f(s[1])) + s[0] becomes
    #return other_f(s[1]) + s[0] becomes
    return s[1] + s[0]
```

It simply swaps the two letters. Let's use the string `'abc'` to see easier what's going on with the next one:

```
def f3(s): # For when len(s)==3
    #if statement is not used
    #return other_f(other_f(s[1:])) + s[0] becomes
    #return f2(f2('bc')) + 'a' becomes
    #return f2('cb') + 'a' becomes
    #return 'bc' + 'a'
    return s[1:] + s[0]
```

Because the function applied to 'bc' swaps them and is applied twice, the function undoes itself. So in this case we've simply put the first letter at the end of the string.

```
def f4(s): # For when len(s)==4
    #return f3(f3(s[1:])) + s[0] becomes
    #return f3(f3('bcd')) + 'a' becomes
    #return f3('cdb') + 'a' becomes
    #return f3('dbc') + 'a' becomes
    #'dbca'
    return s[3] + s[1:3] + s[0] # swap first and last letter

def f5(s): # For when len(s)==5
    #return f4(f4(s[1:])) + s[0]
    #return f4(f4('bcde')) + 'a'
    #swapping first and last letter twice just swaps then swaps back
    #return 'bcde' + 'a'
    return s[1:] + s[0]
```

So it looks like we've got a nice pattern going here - if the string has an even number of letters, swap the first and last letter. If it has an odd number of letters, move the first letter to the end!

... Nope. That pattern ends with `f5`. If you run the function with strings like 'abcd...' you can easily see how each level moves letters around.

```
f | output
----------
f6|'defbca'
f7|'cdbfgea'
f8|'cgefbhda'
f9|'fecihbgda'
```

So as you can see, for longer strings the letters are scrambled around pretty well other than first character always ending up at the end of the string. The best way to think of it is that (with a single line of code) you've managed to write a different function for each length of string (with some functions behaving the same way, like `f3` and `f5`). Each function depends on the function above it, so because `f6` on down pretty well randomize the string, each further function should also randomize the string pretty well.